# How to remover border on video in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How should I remove black border around  tag in Internet Explorer? I've tried changing background-color, adding border:none but none of these worked.

```
<video id="hsense-video" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" autoplay loop muted poster="video/hsense-poster.jpg">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video/hsense-video.mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `!important`?

```css
video {
  border-style: none !important;
}
```

```html
<video id="hsense-video" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" autoplay loop muted poster="video/hsense-poster.jpg">
     <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Yeh I did, same result

Comment: @Giedidius screen shot what you have, the border is not with the video, might be a wrapper / container

Answer (score 0):

I just checked it in Codepen IE browser and there is not border. Also made an html page with the video and checked in IE 11 -> NO BORDER!
https://codepen.io/DannaB67/pen/GErxgx

```
<video id="hsense-video" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" autoplay loop muted poster="video/hsense-poster.jpg">
     <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```